# Implement asynchronous interface synchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have to implement a C# interface method like:

```
Task<Foo> ExecuteAsync();
```

But this particular implementation is actually synchronous.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were on .Net 4.0, you would need to use `TaskCompletionSource`, set its result and then return the `Task`.

On .Net 4.5 / C# 5.0, you have two options: either use `Task.FromResult()` or make your method into an `async` method without any `await`. The second approach will be less efficient and it will generate a warning, so I would go for the first approach.